# Getting JavaScript exception happening in iframe surface

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

Here is the situation:

- A page (`iframe.html`) has an iframe loading another page (`iframe-content.html`).
- An JavaScript error might happen when `iframe-content.html` is loaded in the iframe.
- I'd like that exception to be visible to the browser (e.g. shown in Firefox error console, or Firebug).

Here is what I see:

1. When `iframe.html` is initially loaded, and loads `iframe-content.html` with `src="iframe-content.html"`, the JavaScript exception shows in Firebug.
2. However, if the page is loaded in JavaScript (`document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'iframe-content.html'`), the exception doesn't show.

You can reproduce this by going to:

1. http://avernet.googlepages.com/iframe.html with Firefox.
2. You'll see the exception as `iframe-content.html` is loaded.
3. Click on the button: the content of the iframe is loaded again, but this time the exception doesn't show in Firebug.

Is there a way at #3 to have the exception show, instead of it being silently ignored? (You can't use a try/catch around the JS code that sets the src, as this code returns immediately before the page is loaded in the iframe.)

Comment: What I am describing here isn't an issue with IE. With IE, the error happening when loading the page in the iframe is shown by the browser.

Comment: Works For Me: clicking ‘reload’ spits out another error as expected. But I would indeed be suspicious about the effectiveness of setting a ‘src’ attribute to the value it's already set to. (Modulo absoluteness of the URL, a change you might not want to rely on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your iframe page is not really loaded on the second time. Or it's loaded from the cache and the error is ignored. This is interesting, but I think I found an way around it.

```
function setContent() {
    try {
        console.log("Loading iframe content");
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'iframe-content.html?foo=bar';
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Caught", e);
    }
    console.log("Done loading");
}
```

With that the error should appear.

What I did, was to trick the browser to think that I'm loading a brand new page as the parameters after the url have changed.

```
'iframe-content.html?foo=bar';
```

You could replace my "bar" string with a changing timestamp. Sure, it would avoid the cache, but it would also force it to generate the error like you wished.

Comment: True! The page isn't reloaded. There you go. Thanks Mikko.